# ngx-bootstrap dynamic resizing and wrap tooltip

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

i have a problem with resize tooltip dynamicly. Tootlip does not allow me to dynamic resize, when I set adaptivePosition = true.

I expect that, when I resize window tooltip width tooltip resize together.

Please for help and solution for this problem